# using React-dropzone not able to display Error message for rejectedFiles

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-upload, react-dropzone

I am using below code in my application

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";

const UploadFile = () => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState("");

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    multiple: false,
    onDrop: (acceptedFiles, fileRejections) => {
     console.log('fileRejections', fileRejections)
      });
    }

  return (
    <div{...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} title={title} />
        <p style={{ color: "red", padding: 5, margin: 0, fontSize: 14 }}>
        
        </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am able to get fileRejections rejected  files array if i have  rejected files
it is inside ondrop when i drag and drop or add files in dropzone, but  i dont know how to add errors and display errors to user

Suppose file size too large or limit for file.
Please give me solution for same to display error message

Answer (score 0):

Errors of rejected files can be listed in this way as per the react-dropzone documentation

File size , file type, no. of files need to uploaded can be done here...

```
 const {
  getRootProps,
  getInputProps,
  fileRejections,
  acceptedFiles,
  isDragActive,
  } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: {
  "image/jpeg": [".jpeg", ".jpg"],
  "image/png": [".png"],
  "application/pdf": [".pdf"],
  },
  multiple: true,
  maxSize: 2000000,
  maxFiles:5,
 });

 const fileRejectionItems = fileRejections.map(({ file, errors  }) => { 
 return (
 <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
      <ul>
        {errors.map(e => <li key={e.code}>{e.message}</li>)}
     </ul>

  </li>
 ) 
 });
```